# Data selectors for custom fields

Tags: 8, rules

I have two node types: Item and Order. I have an entity reference (`field_items`) set up on the Order content type which references Item (1 Order to N Items).

The Item has a field (`field_reservation_status`) which is a drop-down list of strings.

I am trying to set up a rule so that when I allocate an Item to an Order on the Order form, the reservation status on the related Item will be set to "Reserved".

I am doing this with a reacting rule and a rule component as follows.

**Rule component**

Condition: Node is of type "Item"

Action: Set a data value (this should set field_reservation_status on the node that the component is actioning to "Reserved")

**Reacting rule**

Event: When a content node is saved

Condition: Node is of type "Order"

Action: Add a variable (this should store field_items for the current Order node)

Then

Action: Call the rule component

**Questions**

1. In the rules config UI I can't see any "Add Loop" button - is this to be expected in version [D8 Alpha 3](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/releases/8.x-3.0-alpha3)?
2. What data selector should I use for accessing field_items on the Order node that has just been saved?
3. What data selector should I use in the rules component to access field_reservation_status on the current object from field_items?
4. How do I set up a loop over the variable that is created in the reacting rule?

No doubt I'll have more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. In the rules config UI I can't see any "Add Loop" button - is this to be expected in version D8 Alpha 3?

***yes*** ... as per the issue about [Implement Loop UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/2660254).

> 2. What data selector should I use for accessing field_items on the Order node that has just been saved?

I doubt this is possible in the [D8-alfa3](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/releases/8.x-3.0-alpha3) release of Rules. Though you may want to retry using the [D8-dev](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/releases/8.x-3.x-dev) release ...

> 3. What data selector should I use in the rules component to access field_reservation_status on the current object from field_items?

Refer to my answer to "2." above ...

> 4. How do I set up a loop over the variable that is created in the reacting rule?

Refer to my answer to "1." above ...

PS: No doubt you'll run into more-of-the-same issues using any of the currently available releases of Rules for D8. However, using the [D8-dev](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/releases/8.x-3.x-dev) release is currently your best bet/alternative.

Comment: Okay, so this has solved the issue to a point. I was getting error messages about fields not existing etc and I no longer get any error messages. However, the rule doesn't seem to have the desired effect.